Getting AWS cognito attributes
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchUserAttributes } from "aws-amplify/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; // Add react-router-dom for navigation

function App(props) {  // No need for WithAuthenticatorProps here in JavaScript
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(""); // Email state
  const [userGroups, setUserGroups] = useState([]); // Explicitly declare as empty array
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // Hook for navigation

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch user attributes, including groups
    fetchUserAttributes().then((userAttrs) => {
      setEmail(userAttrs.email || "");
    })    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching user attributes", error);
    });;
  }, [navigate]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Hello {email}</p>
      <p>
        You can <button onClick={props.signOut}>logout</button>
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I am trying to get the email attribute from the user. Upon logging in, I get this error:
"Error fetching user attributes NotAuthorizedException: Access Token does not have required scopes"
I have already set the scope to include "openid" and "email" when configuring AWS Amplify as well as on the Cognito App Client side. I can log in successfully but cannot retrieve the email. How can I fix this?
I set the scopes to "openid" and "email" here. (and on the App Client)
// Configure AWS Amplify
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          redirectSignIn: ["http://localhost:5173"],
          redirectSignOut: ["http://localhost:5173"],
          domain: "us-east-domain",
          providers: ["Google"],
          scopes: ["openid", "email"],
          responseType: "code",
        },
      },
      userPoolId: "userpoolid",
      userPoolClientId: "userpoolclientid",
    },
  },
});


Hi, can you try to fetch the user first before you fetch attributes in your useEffect?
await getCurrentUser();, just before fetchUserAttributes() in that block?

You should import the getCurrentUser from the amplify/auth package
import { getCurrentUser } from 'aws-amplify/auth'

@SobowaleBukola I tried using getCurrentUser() but got the same error

Then, I am convinced you are yet to add the necessary scope to the scopes in your oauth config.
Add "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin" to your scope array, so it becomes
scopes: ["openid", "email", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin" ],

@SobowaleBukola ah ok thank you!

btw do you know how to get cognito:groups? I realised that it isn't under user attributes so when I try to get groups using fetchUserAttributes() I get undefined.

To get your cognito:groups, you need to decode the token from fetchAuthSession() and access the groups claim.
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
useEffect(()=>{
const { tokens } = await fetchAuthSession();
if (tokens?.idToken) {
const groups = tokens.idToken.payload['cognito:groups'] || [];
  }
})`

@SobowaleBukola the tokens.idToken is undefined... I read that the cognito:groups should indeed be in idToken...

can you get the accessToken ?

@SobowaleBukola ok I can get the groups now! tysm!

Missing "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin", causing the API call to cognito to fail.
